# How to annotate full join

Tags: java, hibernate

I have entity that is join with another table using

@Table

Every time I do a select statement on the entity, those that doesn't have a mapping will not appear.

I guess is doing a LEFT JOIN, may I know if it is possible to do a full outer join?

I retrieve the data using criteria.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Table is not used to join entities. Post the relevant code, tell us precisely what you expect it to do, an what it does instead.

Comment: In addition to @JB Nizet's request, how do you do your select statement? Via Criteria api, via HQL? There are options to *force* a full outer join but they depend on the way you do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using annotations in Hibernate, it makes more sense to use @OneToOne relationships. This abstracts LEFT JOIN using object relational mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this **[join annotation](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/)**  and  **[Hibernate join](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)** also might help you.